# What is the return type of this method?

Tags: c#

I'm very new to programming and have yet to understand methods & return values. I've created the following method. (As my assignment requires) I'm supposed to return a value, but I am unsure what type of value. I've tried returning the matrix I created, but I'll get an error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'Opdracht2.Position'

Sorry if this is a bad question but I don't know how or where else to ask. The method is used to find the position of a specific number in the 2-dimensional array/matrix.

```
class Position
{
    Position FindNumber(int[,] matrix, int findNumber)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Give the number to be searched: ");
        findNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int row = matrix.GetLength(0);
        int col = matrix.GetLength(1);

        int y, x;

        for(y = 0; y < col; y++)
        {
            for(x = 0; x < row; x++)
            {
                if (findNumber == matrix[y, x])
                {
                    return matrix[x, y];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you should create and return an instance of `Position` type, and you didn't share its code with us

Comment: What is the expected _value_ when the number was not found in the matrix? `null` or some special value of `Position` (e.g. `Position.Empty`/`Position.NotFound`) or even an exception being thrown?

Comment: The return type is what you write before the method name, so in this case it's `Position`. `Position` is probably a class, so you should create an instance of that with `new Position(x,y)` or some other constructor that fits.

Answer (score 1):

The return type is the first thing in the function definition line:

```
//  +--- This is the return type
//  |
//  v
Position FindNumber(int[,] matrix, int findNumber)
```

The return type is `Position` which isn't defined in the code you posted. This is a custom type; it can be a struct or a class. It sounds like part of your assignment is to create this custom type, instantiate it in your function, populate it, then return it.

Comment: He's not asking what is return type, he don't understand how to return it.

Comment: It's just a comment and doesn't really answer the question

Comment: Sure looks like he's asking what is the return type to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a tuple (int xPos, int yPos)

```
    public (int xPos, int yPos) FindNumber(int[,] matrix, int findNumber)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Give the number to be searched: ");
        findNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int row = matrix.GetLength(0);
        int col = matrix.GetLength(1);

        int y, x;

        for (y = 0; y < col; y++)
        {
            for (x = 0; x < row; x++)
            {
                if (findNumber == matrix[y, x])
                {
                    return (x, y);
                }
            }
        }
        return (-1, -1);
    }
```

Or if you MUST use Position class instead of

```
return (x, y)
```

you can do

```
return new Position { xPosition = x, yPosition = y };
```

Assuming that you name 2 properties as (x/yPosition)

Comment: OP shared a clean error message _Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'Opdracht2.Position_ The call site expect `Position` type, not the tuple

Comment: Ya, updated the answer to give him 2 ways to solve the issue.